# uitableview searchbar ios5 ARC/storyboard

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard, automatic-ref-counting, uisearchbar

edit: I think the problem is in the last referenced code, because when I try to load the table data instead of the search results (by just swapping the arrays) I still get no search results, but I'm still not sure why... Original post in full:

I'm trying to get a  search bar working with my table view. I can enter text in the  search bar but always  find no results.  Here's my .h

```
@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate> {
IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchBar;
NSMutableArray *dummyArray;
NSMutableArray *searchArray;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *dummyArray;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *searchArray;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *detailArray;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *imageArray;


- (void) setupArray;

- (void) setupSearchArray;

- (void) setupDetailArray;

@end
```

In my .m, dummyArray is  the array that fills the main cell.textLabel.text and the array i want to search.

I set up searchArray here:

```
- (void) setupSearchArray{
searchArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[dummyArray count]]; 
}
```

then attempt to make searchArray a filtered version of dummyArray here:

```
- (BOOL) searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString {
[searchArray removeAllObjects] ;

for (NSString *savedSeachTerm in dummyArray) {



    NSRange result = [savedSeachTerm rangeOfString:searchString options:
                      NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
    if (result.location != NSNotFound)
        [searchArray addObject:savedSeachTerm];

}

return YES;
}
```

and try to populate the table with search results when search text is entered here:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];



}

if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
    cell.textLabel.text = [searchArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [detailArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
else {
    cell.textLabel.text = [dummyArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [detailArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
        if (indexPath.row == 0) {
  cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"row0.png"];
    }
    return cell;    
}
```

What have I done wrong? Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had forgotten to

```
[self setupSearchArray];
```

sorry!